# Como contar caracteres múltiplos de uma string utilizando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Quero contar quantas trincas de base do tipo `ATC` (por exemplo) tem na sequencia `seq`.

O que fiz até agora foi:

```
# CONTAGEM DE NUCLEOTIDEOS
# CONTAGEM DE TRINCAS/CÓDONS DE UMA SEQUENCIA seq

seq = 'ATC CAA GTC AGC TAG CGT ATC ATC GTC ATG CTC AAA CAC TAC GAT GCT AAT'.replace(" ", "")

conta = contt = contc = contg = contador = contATC = 0

for x in seq:
    if x == 'A':
      conta += 1
    if x == 'T':
      contt += 1
    if x == 'C':
      contc += 1
    if x == 'G':
      contg += 1
    if x == 'ATC':       # trinca ATC
      contATC += 1

    contador += 1  # total

print(f'''A quantidade de nucleotideos "A" é {conta},
      de "T" é {contt}, de "C" é {contc}, de "G" é {contg},"ATC" é {contATC}
      assim, o total foi {contador}.''')
```

Podem me criticar construtivamente em relação a outras coisas também, estou aberto a aprender!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se as trincas estão separadas por espaço, uma alternativa é separá-las usando [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) e contar quantas são iguais a "ATC":

```
seq = 'ATC CAA GTC AGC TAG CGT ATC ATC GTC ATG CTC AAA CAC TAC GAT GCT AAT'
atc = 0 # quantidade de ATC
for s in seq.split():
    if s == 'ATC':
        atc += 1
```

Já para contar as letras individualmente, você pode usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(seq)
```

E para obter os totais basta pegá-los do `Counter`:

```
print(f'A quantidade de nucleotideos "A" é {c["A"]}, de "T" é {c["T"]}, de "C" é {c["C"]}, de "G" é {c["G"]}, de "ATC" é {atc}')
```

Quanto ao total geral, bastaria somar os valores do `Counter`, ignorando os espaços:

```
total = sum(qtd for s, qtd in c.items() if s in ('A', 'T', 'C', 'G'))
```

---

Detalhe: quando você itera por uma string (como em `for x in seq`), a cada iteração o `x` será um dos caracteres da string, e portanto ele nunca será igual a "ATC". Sendo assim, seu código não funcionará.

---

Agora se não tiver espaços, uma alternativa é iterar pela string e ir pegando pedaços de 3 em 3:

```
seq = 'ATCGATCTA'
atc = 0
for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
    if seq[i:i + 3] == 'ATC':
        atc += 1
```

Eu uso a sintaxe de *slicing* para pegar determinado trecho da string: `seq[i:i + 3]` pega 3 caracteres a partir da posição `i`, e o `i` vai de zero até o tamanho da string, pulando de 3 em 3. Ou seja, no exemplo acima eu pego primeiro "ATC", depois "GAT" e depois "CTA", e portanto a quantidade de "ATC" será 1.

Nos comentários você disse que usou `count`, mas cuidado que pode dar diferença. Para o exemplo acima, `seq.count('ATC')` resulta em 2, pois "ATC" ocorre 2 vezes na string:

```
ATCGATCTA
^^^ ^^^
 |   |
 |   \_ segunda ocorrência
 \_____ primeira ocorrência
```

Só que a segunda ocorrência eu entendo que está errada, pois o "AT" faz parte da trinca "GAT" e o "C" faz parte do "CTA", então na verdade não é uma ocorrência de "ATC".

Comment: Muito obrigado!! E se a sequência não tivesse os espaços? Como fazer para identificar uma trinca 'ATC'? `seq = 'ATCCAAGTCAGCTAGCGTATCATCGTCATGCTCAAACACTACGATGCTAAT'`

Comment: Suponha que em sua sequencia original você tivesse '... AAT CTC ...' ao remover os espaços você consideraria este ATC como válido? (...AATCTC...). Explique melhor os requisitos.

Comment: Ahhh, entendi, consegui aqui... Usei `seq.count('ATC')` e já é o suficiente... Muito obrigado a todos!

Comment: não esqueça do método "count" - disponível tanto para listas quanto para strings. Para contar as ocorrências de uma única letra ou sequência, funciona bem - mas ele vai percorrer a sequencia principal toda para cada busca, então para contar a ocorrência de várias sequências ao mesmo tempo, pode ser outro jeito. Se os nucleotídeos não começarem em índces multiplos de 3, regular-expressions com ".finditer" - mas mesmo assim só pra sequencias sem sobreposição. Se sobreposições dos nucleotídeos forem possíveis, a coisa pode ser mais complicada.

Comment: @WelingtonSilvaDev Se entendi bem, `count` nem sempre vai funcionar - atualizei a resposta explicando melhor esse detalhe

Comment: @jsbueno, exatamente... Como estou usando o básico ainda, suponho ser uma sequência de lengh múltiplo de 3... Ainda não sei dizer quanto à sobreposição de nucleotídeos, mas caso vir a recair no problema e não solucionar, consultarei aqui novamente. Muito obgd!

Comment: @hkotsubo ficou excelente, muito claro, muitíssimo obrigado!!!!